# Hide element parent jquery

Tags: jquery, parent-child, parent

Hello guys i have this structure of elements when I click on delete the box with the class shared_box should hide it. I tried to do it with parent() and closest but doesn't work. this is my scheme.

```
              <div class="shared_box"> <!--Element to hide -->
                    <div class="user_post">
                     <img src="#" class="pull-left">

                     <!-- Single button -->
                        <div class="btn-group pull-right action_post" style="display: block;">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <!-- element clicked -->
                            <li><a href="#" class="delete" id="13">Delete</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hide Post</a></li>

                          </ul>
                        </div>  
                       </div>
                  </div>
```

**EDIT**

JS

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function() {
            var id_post = $(this);
            bootbox.confirm("Are you sure do want delete?", function(result) {
               if (result) {

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url:  CI_ROOT + 'delete_post',
                        data: "id_post=" + id_post.attr('id') ,
                        success: function(val) {
                            id_post.closest('div.shared_box').hide();
                                    // this one doesn't work
                        }

                    }); 

                } else {
                    console.log("close");
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: Are you sure the html is right? It seems that the div that must be hidden contains the 'hiddener'... Anyway, why use 'parent()' and not the class name?

Comment: `.closest('div.shared_box')` should work.  What did you use?

Comment: are you sure the success callback is getting executed

Comment: What did you meant to match defining var id_post = $(this)?
Do you know that in this case $(this) targets the $(document)?

Answer (score 0):

You must use parents() instead of parent(), because parent() only checks for the immediate ancestor, while parents() checks for all the three in the DOM.

Something like this:

```
$('.delete').on('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('.shared_box').hide();
});
```